# How to find advertiser URL in AdMob so I can block it

Tags: ios, admob, block, ads

I would like to block some ads from showing on my application, but I am unable to find the advertiser URLs to input these into my AdMob account.

Where can I see the advertiser URL for games such as "Clash of Clans" and "Game of War" so I can block these from displaying on my app?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you run your app plugged into your computer through a software proxy, then monitor the network traffic from that software. You can find out the network URLS from there perhaps?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437061/how-do-you-monitor-network-traffic-on-the-iphone

Comment: the most professional way is do anything in admob center but u can do this also using a test device and u can click and open the ad urls with no ban on the test device. good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there to be any easy way to find the URL for specific ads. You may be able to sniff them out if you look very closely at your data traffic.

However, I would advice trying the [Ad review center](https://apps.admob.com/#monetize/pubcontrols%3aarc) on AdMob:

- "Monetize" -> "All apps" -> "Ad Review center"

Once enabled and in "Run ads immediately" mode, you will be able to monitor what targeted ads are shown through your app, and can block the ones you don't like from being shown again. You can either block individual ads or entire AdWords accounts from appearing in your app.

You could also use "Hold placement targeted ads for 24 hours so they can be reviewed", but this only lets you review placement-targeted ads, while the previously mentioned mode works for contextual, interest-based, and placement.

Please note that these ads are blocked for all your apps, not just one. This information can be [verified at Google Support](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3480906?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block ads from **advertiser URL** then you should know the **app/game name**.
Then search that **app/game** on play store using any **browser**, if you got your app/game which ads you want to block then copy its URL.
Remove **https://** from the start of that URL. The **resulting URL** is your advertiser URL
For example in your case you want to block **Clash of Clans** 
Its URL is **https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans&hl=en** 
 and your advertiser URL is **play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans&hl=en** which you can use to block ads in **advertiser URL** of **ADMOB ACCOUNT**.

Comment: the actual URL Clash of Clans and similar games use change very frequently, they use redirects which makes it a lot more difficult.

Comment: what is actual URL, ?