# How to reverse engineer video stream from wifi camera

Tags: camera, video-streaming, reverse-engineering

How can I reverse engineer the video stream URL by looking at the network interface/traffic?

I have a [Panasonic Lumix DMC-FT6](http://www.panasonic.com/au/consumer/lumix-cameras-video-cameras/lumix-digital-cameras/dmc-ft6.html), which has a "wifi mode". I have the iOS [Panasonic Image App](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/panasonic-image-app/id590212732?mt=8). I can setup a HTTP Proxy between the two (using Charles) and see the communication. I can see some "UDP 17" traffic between the iPhone by watching the interface via the method [How do you monitor network traffic on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437061/how-do-you-monitor-network-traffic-on-the-iphone) using Wireshark.

My end goal is to enter a stream URL in VLC and see the video stream.

Unfortunately there is no open source information on this that I can see.

- What is the protocol most likely to be (for a consumer camera)?
- What traits can I look for?
- Are there any obvious URLs worth trying?

Comment: You see HTTP traffic? Or do you see UDP traffic? HTTP doesn't run over UDP. Can you post a look to the packet capture?

Comment: When monitoring the network connection I captured UDP packets which I assume were the video stream - unrelated to the HTTP capture, which was some REST XML API by the looks of things. Will test again and share.